# Difference in the behaviour of deployed app vs local host

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I was trying to create simple app which depended on a random number in nextjs. So I began with that part first. My idea was to create a simple nextjs app which would generate a random number every time it's reloaded/refreshed. So In the beginning I had my code like this :

```
import NumberDisplay from "./components/NumberDisplay";


export default function Home() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

  console.log(randomNumber);
return(
<>
<NumberDisplay RandomNumber = {randomNumber}/>
</>
)
```

When I deployed the above code on vercel,it gave me a constant number on every reload.
after this I created an api and tried to fetch the number from that thinking that it might work but it didn't(In fact it gave me a blank value for random number,even though it worked fine on local host):
The api code:

```
import { NextRequest,NextResponse } from "next/server";

interface numResponse{
    aNumber:number;
}
export const  GET = async(req:NextRequest,res:NextResponse<numResponse>) =>{
    const aNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    console.log(`Number generated in the API:${aNumber}`)
    return NextResponse.json({aNumber},{status:200})

}
```

And now the page.tsx file :

```
import { GET } from "./api/randomNumber/route";

export const generateNumber = () => {
  const aNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  return aNumber;
const generateNumber = async () => {
const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL
  const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/randomNumber`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log("something went wrong");
  } else {
    const newNumber = await response.json();
    console.log(`Fetched Number :`, newNumber);
    return newNumber.aNumber;
  }
};

export default function Home() {
  const randomNumber = generateNumber();
export default async function Home() {
  const randomNumber = await generateNumber();
  return (
<>
<NumberDisplay RandomNumber={randomNumber}/>
</>)
```

when this didn't work out as well,I thought of converting the component into client component and then fetch the number:

```
const generateNumber = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/randomNumber`,
    {
      cache: "no-store",
    }
  );
  const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL;
  const response = await fetch(`/api/randomNumber`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });
  // console.log(`URL:`, process.env.API_URL);
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log("something went wrong");
@@ -20,9 +20,18 @@ const generateNumber = async () => {
  }
};
export default function Home() {
  const [myNumber, setMyNumber] = useState<any>();

  const fetchNumber = async () => {
    const randomNumber = await generateNumber();
    setMyNumber(randomNumber);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNumber();
  }, []);

return(
<>
<NumberDisplay RandomNumber={nyNumber}/>
</>)
```

This one also seemed to work on local host but started to show one number after deployment on vercel.

My **aspiration** was to be able to **generate a unique number on every reload**,

1. Is this a realistic aspiration? I mean is it really possible (or am I just wasting my efforts).
2. If yes then off course I would like to know how can I do that.Am I missing something?

Really Thankful if you made this far and would very much appreciate a helpful response.

Comment: Did you use `export const revalidate = 5` on that page you want to reload/refresh? Note, Every 5 seconds that page will revalidate and fetch new data. This is Time-based Revalidation and Next.js also offers On-demand revalidation. For more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad,I am using {cache:"no-store"},should it not work fine?

Comment: Yes, it should. I thought it would revalidate that page to rerender after 5 seconds. However, the main problem with the API route. Because it is rendered as static on build time. That's why every time you reload or refresh, you'll get the same constant number from the cache (on build time generated random number).

Comment: @ 
Golamrabbi Azad,yes that is confusing me,I thought it should generate a unique number everytime

Comment: So, has your confusion cleared?  And, do you have any questions for me?

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad,no it hasn't but now I don't know what to ask

Comment: By default, Next.js attempts to pre-render all pages and API routes. Add this line `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";` to your `api/randomNumber/route.ts` file. It will make the API dynamic. So, every time you reload the browser, it will generate a new number.
Now, that your API route is dynamic, you need to make your page dynamic too. To make the page dynamic, simply add the same line to your `page.tsx` file. That's it.

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad, Thank you so much for replying to my post and comments. I had been at it for a while and for now I have done it through client side rendering BUT in my next attempt,I will surely try this. Thank you again.